# Store and read private key securely

Tags: php, security, private-key, private

i'm wondering what would be the best way to store private key in web server and read it from web apps?

So far the action taken is the directory of private key will deny all access from browser, and the directory files can be read and write by privilege user but i'm afraid it is still insufficient.

Comment: What kind of private key are you talking about? The server key for SSL? That shouldn't be readable from webapps at all only for the server daemon but it shouldn't be stored in a directory accessible from the web or read by web applications

Comment: not ssl more on exchange cert key

Comment: use a smart card or hardware security module